# Have an a href link to a variable twitter handle in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, haml, href

I'm trying to make a link that goes to a user's twitter account dynamically via a Twitter handle. The problem is the Twitter handle is just `@variablehandle`, not a full site link.

I figured out how to link to Facebook dynamically but Twitter was a fail, so maybe this can help you guys help me.

Both the Twitter and Facebook variables are present here.  Also, we are using HAML:

```
- unless @user.facebook_url.blank?
  %a{:href => @user.facebook_url}
    click here


-unless @user.twitter_handle.blank?
  %a{:href => "https://twitter.com/" + @user.twitter_handle}
    click me
```

Comment: what error message are you receiving?

Comment: o shit it works nevermind loll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `link_to` helper to make life easier:

```
- unless @user.facebook_url.blank?
  =link_to "click here", @user.facebook_url

- unless @user.twitter_handle.blank?
  =link_to "click me", "https://twitter.com/" + @user.twitter_handle
```